# Dynamically creating an object using eval() JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to dynamically create an object in javascript. Here is the JS code that I have written:

```
var table = $("#eidtPersonalInfoTbl");
var trs = table.find('tr');

var obj = { };

$(trs).each(function(index, row){
     var field = $(row).find('td').eq(0).html();
     var value = $(row).find('td').eq(1).html();
     eval('obj.' + field + ' = ' + value );
});
```

And here is the HTML markup for the table:

```
<table class="table" border="1" id="eidtPersonalInfoTbl">
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Name </td>
    <td class="span5"> Name </td>       
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone"> Address</td>
    <td class="span5"> Address </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone">Area</td>
    <td class="span5"> Area</td>                                        
<tr>
<tr>
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone">Gender</td>
    <td>Male</td>                                                       </tr>           
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Salutation </td>
    <td class="span5"> Dr</td>                                      
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone">State</td>
    <td class="span5"> State </td>                                          
<tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone">City</td>
    <td class="span5"> City </td>                                       
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Postel Code </td>
    <td class="span5"> Postel Code </td>                                        
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Phone# </td>
    <td class="span5"> 04128741 </td>                                       
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Mobile# </td>
    <td class="span5"> 03218741525</td>                                     
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="span3 hidden-phone" > Cover Letter </td> 
    <td>Cover letter goes here</td>
</tr>                       
<tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="per-det" class="btn btn-success span5" value="Update and Cont."></td>
</tr>
```

Whenever I try to execute this, it gives me this error

> Undefined variable Name

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the value string. Try `eval('obj.' + field + ' = "' + value + '"' );`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's far easier, safer and faster to use this:

```
obj[field] = value;
```

... instead of `eval('obj.' + field + ' = "' + value + '"')`, which obviously has the same purpose.

You see what you see now because `value` should be wrapped in the quotation marks. For example, if both `field` and `value` are equal to `'Name'` (string), the evalled expression as it stands now will look like...

```
obj.Name = Name
```

... obviously causing the 'Undefined variable Name' error.

---

Two sidenotes here. First, there's no sense wrapping `trs` in jQuery object again in this line...

```
$(trs).each(function(index, row)
```

... as it already IS a jQuery object (result of `table.find('tr')`). This redundancy is easier to see if you follow a simple convention: preceding names of all the variables that are used to store jQuery objects with `$`:

```
var $table = $("#eidtPersonalInfoTbl");
var $trs   = $table.find('tr');
// ...

// $($trs) - obviously redundant
```

Second, it's a bit wasting to go through DOM twice in these lines:

```
 var field = $(row).find('td').eq(0).html();
 var value = $(row).find('td').eq(1).html();
```

I'd rather have it rewritten it like this:

```
 var $tds = $(row).find('td');
 var field = $tds.eq(0).html(); // or just $tds[0].innerHTML;
 var value = $tds.eq(1).html(); // or just $tds[1].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. Don't forget javascript objects are nothing more than an associative array.